# Joining two tables with two results from one table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a question that I can't seem to figure out the correct way to search for it.
I have two tables that I need to join to get two results off one

```
teams table

id    name
------------
1     team A
------------
2     team B
```

```
games table 

id   home_team   away_team
--------------------------
1    1           2 
--------------------------
2    2           1
```

The above should result as

```
game_id   home_team   away_team 
-------------------------------
1         team A      team B
-------------------------------
2         team B      team A
```

The confusion starts out as `"SELECT teams.name AS home_team, teams.name AS away_team"` which obviously doesn't make any sense.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to link to the same table twice and use aliases:

```
select g.game_id, h.name as home_team, a.name as away_team
from games g
join teams h on h.id = g.home_team
join teams a on a.id = g.away_team
```

So you're linking to the teams table aliasing it as `h` for the home team, and linking to it again aliasing it as `a` for the away team.

Comment: this makes complete sense and works flawlessly. I didn't know about just joining twice. Thank you!